# Select2 : Get the previous selected option value from my 1st select

Tags: php, jquery, select, jquery-select2

I have 2 select2 dropdown.

1) Put some validation, when the value is already selected in select 1 it will now disable in select 2.

2) Now if the user change the value of select 1, the value of previous in select 1 it will now enable in select 2

```
Example

Select 1 = A - selected
           B
           C
Select 2 - A - disabled
           B 
           C 

User changed the value in Select 1

Select 1 - A
           B
           C - selected
Select 2 - A - will now enable.
           B
           C - disabled
```

Question: How can I enable the previous value of the first selected value in select 1?

**Jquery**

```
$(document).on('select2:select', '#warehouse_from', function(e){
        //send ajax request
        var id         = $(this).val(); 
        var val        = $('#warehouse_from option:selected').text();
        $('select#warehouse_to>option[value="'+id+'"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        getItemsByWarehouse(id);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: You should include a verifiable example - so others are more encouraged to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the user interacts with one `select2` dropdown... The game is over. The instance cannot be changed. So the `disabled` property you can programmatically set to he *original* `select` element won't reflect...

The trick to walk around that is to [*destroy*](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods#destroying-the-select2-control) the instance and re-instantiate it.

See comments in code.

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/mYmXLB?editors=1010)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // On page load instantiation for both select2
  $('.example').select2();

  // On change handler for the 1st select
  $(document).on('change', '#one', function(e){

    // To avoid too many lookups... Store the second select in a variable
    var two = $("#two");

    // If the selected value in 1st select is ALREADY selected in 2nd select, clear it.
    if( two.val() == $(this).val() ){
      two.val(null);
    }

    // Reset the select2 instance (destroy and re-instantiate),
    // Reset the disabled properties
    // Disable the right option
    two.select2('destroy').select2();
    two.find("option").prop("disabled",false);
    two.find("[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").prop("disabled",true);
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="example" id="one">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select class="example" id="two">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```